# devise : new user registration issues , PG::ProtocolViolation . Rails4, Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, omniauth, rails-postgresql

I am using devise and omni-auth to login with linkedin .

I added the from_omniauth method to user model as mentioned in the Railscast:

This is the code:

```
#Create a new user if does not exist   
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create! do |user|
       user.provider = auth.provider
       user.uid = auth.uid
       user.email = auth.info.email
    end
end


Started GET "/users/auth/linkedin/callback?oauth_token=XXX" 
INFO -- omniauth: (linkedin) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by OmniauthCallbacksController#linkedin as HTML

   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'email@yahoo.com' LIMIT 1
  SQL (3.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "provider", "uid", "updated_at") VALUES ('2013-11-12 06:50:57.811205', 'email@yahoo.com', 'linkedin', 'XXXX', '2013-11-12 06:50:57.811205') RETURNING "id"  *[["created_at", Tue, 12 Nov 2013 06:50:57 UTC +00:00], ["email", "email@yahoo.com"], ["provider", "linkedin"], ["uid", "XXXX"], ["updated_at", Tue, 12 Nov 2013 06:50:57 UTC +00:00]]*
**PG::ProtocolViolation: ERROR:  bind message supplies 5 parameters, but prepared statement "a1" requires 0**
: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "provider", "uid", "updated_at") VALUES ('2013-11-12 06:50:57.811205', 'XXXX@yahoo.com', 'linkedin', 'ts2xg5e6d9', '2013-11-12 06:50:57.811205') RETURNING "id"
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 117ms

PG::ProtocolViolation - ERROR:  bind message supplies 5 parameters, but prepared statement "a1" requires 0
```

I am having a hard time figuring out why a correct query is not generated. If I copy the insert statement and run it ..the record gets inserted in the db fine. But its generating those extra parameters after returning Id .. in the query above.

Any idea how to resolve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL with Rails4 ??

Comment: Yes, Is there something I need to change ? .The issues started propping up after upgrading to Rails4 but I am not able to link it to anything partiular

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12330 . This led me to believe its related to prepared statements since I also saw Active record cache throwing exceptions. I enabled prepared statements in database.yml and it worked fine again ! . I will let someone explain the issue and solution in detail and accept that answer